# Is it possible to change the labels of primeng piechart dynamically based on list of values in angular2 application

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular2 web application I have to display piechart for list of values. this list changes at runtime. Can we change the labels, values and color of piechart accordingly.Is there any examples to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by getting the values in the list.

```
this.piedata = {
                    labels: this.bayGroupList,
                    datasets: [{
                                    data: this.bayCountList,
                                    backgroundColor:this.bayColorList,
                                    hoverBackgroundColor:this.bayColorList
                                }]
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG Charts are based off of ChartJS.

For Pie Chart, this would be how you set it up

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
type: 'pie',
data: data,
options: options
```

});

then for your data:

```
data = {
datasets: [{
    data: [value1, value2, value3]
}],
```

Values for pie charts should be `number` since the chart will calculate the total and display the chart proportionally and accordingly.

There's a function `update` where you can manipulate the data array of your specific chart (myPieChart in this case) then call `myPieChart.update()` to update the chart dynamically.

Same for `options`, define some properties then bind those properties to the `options` as `labels` and such so you can dynamically and programmatically change them.

I do not have an example right at the moment but you can try it out.